# Estimate demand function with Tobit and Hurdle models

Tags: stata

I am running Tobit and hurdle models with education expenditure data. Naturally, many observations are zero, for those who do not incur the expenditure (out of school, receiving scholarship etc.), hence I am using the Tobit and hurdle models. Ideally, I would like to get estimates of income elasticity: how is the proportional increase in expenditure correlated with proportional increase in income? To do this, I need to take a log transformation of the dependent variable (expenditure). However, due to the presence of the zeros, taking a log doesn't seem reasonable to me. Further, running a Tobit on transformed data results in "no censored observations" since the lower limit is not zero any more. My questions are:

1. Should I add 1 to expenditure, take a log and run Tobit with `ll(0)`? How to obtain the elasticity estimates in this case?
2. The user-written `nehurdle` command allows the `exponential` option which automatically transforms the dependent variable into a log. If I use this option, will `margins` give me a direct estimate of elasticity?

Please suggest how to proceed.

Note: I am using `nehurdle` and not `churdle` because I am working with Stata12.1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't focused on a specific reproducible issue with the OP's code. It mixes a request for statistical advice with an open-ended request to recommend code. An answer to #2 is pretty hard work unless someone here is the author of `nehurdle` and in any case the answer depends on statistical knowledge of what various commands do.

Comment: #2 seems dubious given the existence of zeros. Automatic logging can only convert your zeros to missings. Any downstream estimate of elasticity will be made possible that way, if I understand correctly. If a variable can be zero, why is elasticity a relevant idea?

Comment: @NickCox Please suggest an appropriate forum for Stata related questions other than Statalist. However, I have seen such questions asked and answered on this platform, so I am unclear how is my question off-topic. Should I include code to improve the question?

Comment: Regarding your comment on the interpretation of elasticity, I had read that for demand estimation equations, interpretation using elasticity rather than absolute change is the standard method. Could you suggest another appropriate interpretation? 
Also, `churdle` works pretty much the same way as `nehurdle`, and also has the exponential option.

Comment: What’s wrong with Statalist? Your post being off-topic is my view but it remains open for others to answer as I write. Sorry, but I know nothing about demand estimation equations, but that is much of my point: this isn’t a straight programming question.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps I should post on an econometrics forum. Thanks for the response.

Comment: That sounds a good idea to me. You didn’t explain your aversion to Statalist, but many more econometricians and applied economists hang out there than watch the Stata tag here.